# Netlogo world is 500x500, making the text on the buttons too small. How can I change the size of the text on the buttons?

Tags: gis, netlogo

In Netlogo, I am using the gis extension to import a boolean raster. The cell has a value of 0 indicating the absence of some feature and a value of 1 indicating the presence of some feature. The original raster is 558 rows x 615 columns.

If I resize the world to be large (even 250 x 250), I need to use CTRL - so that I can see the entire world in the GUI. This results in the text on my buttons being too small.
[image]

If I resize the world to be 10% of its original size and smaller (so it fits nicely in the GUI), the sampling algorithm down samples my raster so that I lose a lot of data.

[image]

How can I change the size of the text on my buttons?

Here is my code:

```
extensions [gis]

globals[
  water-data ;;water data
]

patches-own[
  is_water
]

to setup
  clear-all
  reset-ticks
  ask patches [set pcolor white]
  resize-world 0 61 0 55
  set water-data gis:load-dataset "data/water_con.asc"
  gis:set-sampling-method water-data "BICUBIC"
  gis:set-world-envelope-ds gis:envelope-of water-data
  gis:apply-raster water-data is_water
  ask patches with [is_water = 1][set pcolor gray + 1]

end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no way to edit the font size used by widgets in the NetLogo interface tab in code or config.  You can adjust the zoom settings using Ctrl+ or Ctrl-, but that only lasts until you close the model, as you found.

You can adjust the **Patch size** of the view, however.  Right click on the view and go to **Edit...** to open the **Model Settings** dialog.  [Docs for these settings are here](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/interfacetab.html#the-2d-and-3d-views).

[image: setting patch size to 1 in model settings]

If you set the **Patch size** to `1` you can get single pixel per patch, which looks as below.  This is with a world of size 558x615.  This looks about as usable to me as the "low resolution" solution you put in the question.

[image: model with 500x500 size with patch size 1]

You can even set a fractional patch size, but the smallest I'd recommend going is 0.5.  I'm actually not 100% sure that's totally supported, and it'll definitely make your model almost impossible to see.